# Why can't i insert into mysql database using php?

Tags: php, mysql, database

this is my code:

```
 $query = "INSERT INTO accounts (name, mail, group, year, active, password) VALUES  ('$name', '$email', '$group', '$year', '1', '$pass')";          
 $result = mysql_query($query) or DIE(mysql_error());
```

this is my DB

```
Field -  Type 
id       int(11) (auto increment)
name     varchar(30)
mail     varchar(30)
group    varchar(4)
year     varchar(3)
active   tinyint(1)
password varchar(36)
```

and i get this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'group, year, active, password) VALUES ('Smith S. Ana Joy', 'ana' at line 1

an example or the variables that i am adding:

```
$name = Smith
$email = ana.smith
$group = A1
$year = I
$active = 1
$pass = a
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Syntax error due to using a reserved word as a table or column name in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446377/syntax-error-due-to-using-a-reserved-word-as-a-table-or-column-name-in-mysql)

Answer (score 3):

`GROUP` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) in mySQL.

Wrap it in backticks:

```
`group`
```

or use a different column name.

Also make sure your code is protected against [SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) (i.e. each variable is being sanitized before being inserted into the code).

Comment: Always quote your queries. you have a few keywords in there, "group", "password", and "year" are all mysql keywords.

$query = "INSERT INTO accounts (`name`, `mail`, `group`, `year`, `active`, `password`) VALUES  ('$name', '$email', '$group', '$year', '1', '$pass')";          
 $result = mysql_query($query) or DIE(mysql_error());

Answer (score 1):

`GROUP` is a reserved word. You should quote that column name:

```
... mail, `group`, ...
```

Answer (score 1):

group is a MYSQL-command and may not be used like that in a value. Escape the field like so:

"INSERT INTO accounts (name, mail, \"group\", year, active, password) VALUES  ('$name', '$email', '$group', '$year', '1', '$pass')";

Answer (score 1):

`Group` is a reserverd word in MySQL and therefore you must qoute it. You can read more about it here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Answer (score 0):

`group` is a reserved keyword, you should enclose it in backticks.